# How do I download the javascript library for mapstraction v2?

Tags: drupal, javascript, mapstraction

I am setting up a map on a drupal website using the mapstraction module. I am planning to use the 6.x-2.x-dev development branch of mapstraction because I need some of its additional functionality.

In the instructions for installing the module, it says to download the mapstraction v2 library from mapstraction.com  Navigating through their site, I found this page:
code.google.com/p/mapstraction/source/checkout which tells you:

> Command-line access
>
> Use this command to anonymously check out the latest project source code:
>
> '# Non-members may check out a read-only working copy anonymously over HTTP.
>
> svn checkout http://mapstraction.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ mapstraction-read-only

I don't understand what command-line access is? I've tried pasting mapstraction.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ into my browser, and I get a whole directory listing. Do I download each of these files? How do I know what is actually the mapstraction v2 library? Am I going about accessing the javascript library in the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a **Subversion Client**. The Apache project maintains a [**list**](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html) where you should be able to find a client for your operating system. Once you have a client, you will have to perform the "Checkout" function on the url provided by Google Code. Once you have the directory downloaded by the SVN client, you can look at the examples for proper usage and file inclusion.

Answer (score 1):

They moved to git hub. 
You can now just download the zip file from here without a client installed
https://github.com/mapstraction/mxn/downloads